# Ruby on Rails - Setting a Custom Route with Custom Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-action, custom-routes

i'm a RoR beginner using rails 3.2.3.

I have a products resource and a nested Availability resource under it.

My routes are:

```
/products/:product_id/availabilities
```

which is working great.

However, my availability model allows to set the price of the product on an exact date, for e.g.: today the product 'x' will have 'y' availability (it is an integer) and 'z' price (price is also an attribute of the Availability Model).

My question is, I now want to add a page that allows the modification of prices (**without** creating a new Price Model), similar to the one I have for availability. I'm only using the index action, as it will show all the availabilities for that only selected product.

How can I create a route like:

```
/products/:product_id/availabilities/prices
```

I tried adding this to my routes rb:

```
 match '/products/:id/availabilities/prices', :action => 'indexP', :via => [:get], :controller => 'prices'
 match '/products/:id/availabilities/prices', :action => 'createP', :via => [:post], :controller => 'prices'
```

It is worth noting that I am using a `prices controller` to interact with the same availability model, but that shouldn't be a problem.

I also created in that `prices controller` the `indexP` and `createP` actions.
In my Availabilities View I created an `indexP.html.erb` to differentiate from the regular `index.html.erb` which contains the availabilities.

And when I run `rake routes` I get:

```
$ rake routes | grep prices
                            GET    /products/:id/availabilities/prices(.:format)
                            POST   /products/:id/availabilities/prices(.:format)
```

Which is great. However, when I access that URL, I get:

```
NoMethodError in Availabilities#show
{"product_id"=>"46",
 "id"=>"prices"}
```

Why is it doing the `show` action instead of my custom match?

*Note*: I am **not** after something like: /products/:id/availabilities/:id/prices

just :/products/:id/availabilities/prices

I know this is probably a dumb question but I would appreciate any tips to help me understand what is going on.

Thanks in advance,
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your product model setup?

If it something like:

```
resources :products do
  resources :availabilities
end
```

the first match the route does goes to the show action of the availabilities controller.

You have two options here. Limit the availabilities controller scope, with:

```
resources :products do
  resources :availabilities, :only => [:index]
end
```

or to place your custom match before this block

```
match '/products/:id/availabilities/prices', :action => 'indexP', :via => [:get], :controller => 'prices'
match '/products/:id/availabilities/prices', :action => 'createP', :via => [:post], :controller => 'prices'
```

Note that this routes are not restfull. This may get you in trouble later :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh my...I can't believe all it took was to position that block before the previous block...I totaly forgot this important aspect: `first created -> highest priority.` Thanks robertokl, and although I also believe in case the app needs to scale that this can get me into trouble, I thank you for helping me so quickly. Although I advise anyone else with this question to create a new model so that the future-trouble can be avoided. Anyways, marked as answered, regards